# why does body onload work but window.onload or document.onload NOT work

Tags: javascript

So I want to hide a div, so I have my code

```
function hide(){hide div code}

document.onload = hide();
```

*Does not work.*

```
window.onload = hide();
```

*Does not work.*

**However if I go to the HTML document and write**

```
<body onload="hide()">
```

*This works.*

Now I understand that I should not have javascript in the html document, but how do I actually make the javascript WAIT until the entire page has loaded and then execute some code. I am certain that the code is running before the page has loaded, and I just cant work out why.

Do you have any ideas on how I can make this work?

Answer (score 2):

To make this work, you have to pass the function itself instead of calling it and passing the value it returns.

It means you have to write:

```
window.onload = hide;  // Without parentheses.
```

In passing, note that [onload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.onload) is only supported by `window`, not `document`.

Comment: It doesnt seem to be working. Even the alert I put in to test doesnt work, however it (the alert) does work when I have the parenthesis

Comment: When are you assigning your handler to `window.onload`? If you do that too late, the `load` event may have already fired.

Comment: The window.onload is at the top of the page

Comment: I fixed it, it was another JS element causing trouble

Comment: Thanks for noting that document.onload = hide (without the parentheses) does not work.

Answer (score 1):

Also, you can try calling your code like this:

```
window.onload = function () { hide(); }
```

Comment: Sorry, try window.onload instead of document.onload

Answer (score 0):

Yeah I fixed it, it was another JS element causing trouble with my function!